# Trigger task after upstream task statuses are known and at least one of them is successful

Tags: airflow

I have a requirement as below, but none of the `trigger_rule`s seem to be able to deliver the expected behaviour

Suppose task D has two upstream tasks

- U1: 1 second
- U2: 100 second (much longer than U1)

I want task D to be triggered only when

- Both U1 and U2 are successful
- U1 is successful, U2 is skipped (not failed)

---

To be more exact, examples of scenarios where D should be triggered include

- C1: both U1 and U2 succeeded
- C2: U1 was skipped, and U2 succeeded

And examples of scenarios where D should be skipped include

- C3: U1 failed, and U2 succeeded
- C4: both U1 and U2 were skipped
- C5: U1 failed, and U2 skipped

---

I have tried to following `trigger_rule`s for D but none of them delivers the behaviour I want because

1. `all_success`: D will not be triggered in scenario C2
2. `one_sucess`: D will be triggered immediately after U1 succeeds without waiting for U2 in scenario C2
3. `all_done`: D will be triggered in even in scenario C4

Comment: `ExternalTaskSensor` seems to be capable of this but that doesn't sound very neat. Moreover general fervour advises against using them

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xcom to do this functionality.
Basically, you can have the upstream task set some key and value by pushing using     `xcom_push` and downstream pull it to use it `xcom_pull()`

Docs here:
https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms

Example on the Airflow repo here:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I understand your solution, but it is not the type of solution I'm looking for. The solution basically embeds the 'trigger rule' in imperative code. However, the whole point to have Airflow is to make those 'trigger rule' or dependencies between tasks delcarative and visible without digging into code.